# Why are there so many users named "user<random number>"?

Tags: discussion

Are the deleted users automatically renamed to user<random number>, e.g. user354353, or user240249 or are they actually naming their accounts like this?

Comment: The number isn't random, it's the unique (per site) user identification number, which is sequential. e.g. first user to register has 1 as their id, second has 2 etc.